# Move File To Sub-Directories

Tags: c#, .net

Moving files is easy & clear in `.NET` what gets me is how to move to a `sub-directory`  For example, let's say I have a file in my source destination called Joe_2.mp3, and I need to move it to destination directory and to the most recently modified `sub-folder` if one exists.  If it does not just move it straight into the destination directory.  How would I 1st check for sub-directories & if they exist find the most recently modified one and move the source file their?

This is what I was using when it was just a straight move from `directory1` to `directory2`

```
private string source = @"C:\\First\\";
private string unclear = @"C:\\Second\\";
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DirectoryInfo FirstCheck = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\First\\");
  DirectoryInfo SecondCheck = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\Second\\");
  IEnumerable<string> list1 = FirstCheck.GetFiles("*.*").Select(fi => fi.Name);
  IEnumerable<string> list2 = SecondCheck.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(fi => fi.Name);
  IEnumerable<string> missing = list1.Except(list2);
  foreach (var file in missing)
  {
    var subdi = new DirectoryInfo(SecondCheck.ToString());
    var direcetories = subdi.EnumerateDirectories().OrderBy(d => d.CreationTime).Select(d => d.Name).ToList();
    File.Move(source, unclear);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Directory.GetDirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the paths of all the subdirectories, then use the [`Directory.GetCreationTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the info you need.  Then you can just sort them and take the minimal value that matches your criteria.

Comment: Will you look at my edit and how would I select the most recently modified directory?

Comment: Try adding a '.First()' at the end of that `var direcetories` line to take the first element in the resultant sequence.  That would give you the first created directory.  Take the .Last() if you want the last created directory.